# How to use Guava functions declared for a generic super-type on a sub-type?

Tags: java, generics, guava

I know the title isn't terribly descriptive, but I couldn't really come up with something better. This is more about my (lack of) general understanding of generics than about Guava.

Let's suppose I have an interface like this:

```
public interface HasId {
  String getId();
}
```

And I have a function declared like this:

```
private static Function<? extends HasId, String> getId = new Function<HasId, String>() {
    public String apply(HasId input) {
        return input.getId();
    }
};
```

Why can't I use this function in e.g. an ordering like this (which generates a compiler error that getId is of the wrong generic type):

```
List<String> ids = ...;
List<SomeTypeImplementingHasId> someStuff = ...;
Ordering<SomeTypeImplementingHasId> byIds = Ordering.explicit(ids).onResultOf(getId);
List<SomeTypeImplementingHasId> sortedByGivenIds = byIds.sortedCopy(someStuff);
```

I know I can do it with a wrapper function casting it like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T extends HasId> Function<T, String> getIdFunc() {
    return (Function<T, String>)getId;
}
```

But isn't there some way that doesn't need this unchecked cast?

**Edit:** This solved my problem, thanks @Natix & @Jean Logeart:

I first had to get rid of the wildcard in the function declaration:

```
Function<HasId, String> getId = ...
```

and then I had to change my ordering to be typed on the super-class also:

```
Ordering<HasId> byIds = Ordering.explicit(ids).onResultOf(getId);
```

Comment: Just declare the function like this `Function<HasId, String> getId`. The wildcard isn't useful there.

Comment: @Natix Ok, that fixes the transform. Still have an issue using it with Ordering<T>, going to modify the question in a sec.

Comment: [Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem? **Include any error messages**, key APIs, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- Declare `Function<HasId, String> getId = ...`
- Declare `Function<? super HasId, String> getId = ...`

More info: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)